# Why $\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\mu)^2 + \mu^2 \tau^2 = (n+\tau^2)(\mu-\frac{\sum x_i}{n+\tau^2})^2$

Tags: statistics

We are trying to show that the first expression is a normal distribution (the random variable here is $\mu$ not $x$). And so they do this transformation to obtain that $\mu | x_1, ..., x_n \sim N(\frac{\sum x_i}{n+\tau^2}, (n+\tau^2)^-1)$. But I do not understand how they factor it like that, unfortunately.

We can do this, but what does it give us:
$-n\mu^2\sum x_i^2 + \mu^2\tau^2 = \mu^2 (\tau^2 - n\sum x_i^2)$

Comment: I think I'm seeing it now

Comment: Nice. You can post an answer and thus other users can comprehend the transformation.

Comment: I thought I saw it, but I didn't.. It's from here: http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~rrw1/stats/Sa4.pdf (page 31 pdf, actual number on page 23; bottom of the page)